# Issue with accessing https

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I have an app build in Laravel but have issues in accessing pages through https. Example, if I access geepay.in, the app redirects to https

However, if I access http://geepay.in/9860494211 it redirects to https domain index.php

(Also if I remove the script from htacess, the app stops working and throws error).

My htacess files contains the following

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#Hadle https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55  .php55 .php
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: what error do you get

Answer (score 0):

You simply fix this issue by swapping the rewrite and https-redirect. In your case, Apache will match rule 2 first. Then rule 1 and 2 do no longer match and you match rule 3. Since you have already rewritten the url, you perform the redirect with the rewritten url.

If you swap the rules, the redirect will be matched first. Afterwards, the new request will match your rule 2 (then 3), and let Laravel handle the request.